# mongodb connection not getting closed in Spring-boot

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

My **SpringConfig.xml** says:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.10.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <mongo:mongo-client id="mongo" host="127.0.0.1" port="27017" >

<mongo:client-options
     connections-per-host="8"
     threads-allowed-to-block-for-connection-multiplier="4"
     connect-timeout="1000"
     max-wait-time="1500"
     socket-keep-alive="true"
     socket-timeout="1500"
    />
</mongo:mongo-client>

    <mongo:db-factory dbname="test" mongo-ref="mongo" />

<bean id="mappingContext"
    class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext" />

 <bean id="defaultMongoTypeMapper"
    class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DefaultMongoTypeMapper">
    <constructor-arg name="typeKey"><null/></constructor-arg>
 </bean>

 <bean id="mappingMongoConverter"
    class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    <constructor-arg name="mappingContext" ref="mappingContext" />
    <property name="typeMapper" ref="defaultMongoTypeMapper" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    <constructor-arg name="mongoConverter" ref="mappingMongoConverter" />
 </bean>

</beans>
```

I am calling this only once in constructor of my service:

```
ApplicationContext ctx; 
public DoctorService() {

    ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext("SpringConfig.xml"); 
}
```

And then using **ctx** like:

```
MongoOperations mongoOperation = (MongoOperations) ctx.getBean("mongoTemplate");
Query searchUserQuery = new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is( new ObjectId(userId)));

Keys k = new Keys();
Doctor doctor = mongoOperation.findOne(searchUserQuery, Doctor.class);
k.setSessionId(doctor.getSessionid());
k.setToken(doctor.getToken());
List<Keys> keys = new ArrayList<Keys>();
keys.add(k);
return keys;
```

However, the connection is not getting closed, even after the timeout period.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: What is your expectation ? Do you want a new connection for each query ?

Comment: @Veeram , when I run db.serverStatus().connections I get the increased  connections under current key , than before I sent the request

Answer (score 1):

There is a max 100 sized connection pool for each mongo template (as default), and these are reused again & again for speed, so the connections will not be closed, that is `connections-per-host="8"` in your mongo client options. So you will have at most 8 connections, and they will stay as long as your app stays. To have auto

***EDIT:***  To kill connections, you can use the following property to have them commit suicide with a timer `maxConnectionIdleTime: 1000`, so any idle connection that has a idle time > 1000ms will be killed, this does work, I've tested & the change of connection pool size can be seen below;

[image]

Spike after server restart is my load test, and it did not reach its full connection pool limit, and after peaking, the connections were killed. Though it must be said that the connection creation is indeed really costly, my response time increased more than hundredfold, so not the best solution not having a connection pool, though it would be better to have a somewhat long `maxConnectionIdleTime` so only after a long inactivity you'd start killing connections, and also having a `minConnectionsPerHost` value, so you'd always have a decent amount of connection pool ready, if needed you'd increase it, then kill the excess when server is less active, rinse and repeat!

Comment: @Satya I've updated my answer, I think this will be useful for you!